# What is wrong with this comparison that it won't see to compare to values correctly?

Tags: bash

I am trying to find the oldest date (in string format) out of a list of elements.
I can't figure out why the comparison is not working which results in the oldest date found always being the temporary oldest date as seen here:

```
filedates=(20200110 20200120 20200219 20200220 20200420 20200422 20200110 20200120 20200219 20200220 20200420 20200422 20200219 20200220 20200420 20200422)

find_oldest_date (){
    arr=("$@")
    currentOldestDate=${arr[0]} # set a temporary oldest date
    echo "Temporary oldest date: "$currentOldestDate
    for date in "${arr[@]}"; do
     currentDate=$date
    if [[ "$currentDate" -lt "$currentOldestDate" ]]; then
      oldestDateFound=$currentDate
     else
      oldestDateFound=$currentOldestDate
     fi
    done
    echo "Oldest date found in directory: "$oldestDateFound
}
find_oldest_date "${filedates[@]}"
```

for the comparison I've also tried:

```
 if [[ "$currentDate" < "$currentOldestDate" ]]
```

Or with only single brackets and double quotes, or double brackets no quotes ...

Its a requirement to pass filedates in as a parameter rather then use it directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you are always comparing `$currentDate` (the actual date in the list you are traversing) against `$currentOldestDate` (which is just the first element of the array, it is not "current"). You must compare the `$currentDate` against an accumulator that contains the oldest date found so far and update as needed:

```
filedates=(20200110 20200120 20200219 20200220 20200420 20200422 20200110 20200120 20200219 20200220 20200420 20200422 20200219 20200220 20200420 20200422)

find_oldest_date (){
    arr=("$@")
    currentOldestDate="${arr[0]}" # set a temporary oldest date
    echo "Temporary oldest date: $currentOldestDate"
    for date in "${arr[@]}"; do
        if [[ "$date" -lt "$currentOldestDate" ]]; then
            currentOldestDate="$date"
        fi
    done
    echo "Oldest date found in directory: $currentOldestDate"
}
find_oldest_date "${filedates[@]}"
```

Comment: That was the idea, to fix what you had. There are a number of things that can be made better, but this was not the point.

Answer (score 1):

You never change the value of `currentOldestDate` from its initial value of `${arr[0]}`. As a result, you are reporting the last date seen that is less than `${arr[0]}`, not necessary the *oldest* date seen.

```
find_oldest_date (){
    arr=("$@")
    oldestDateFound=${arr[0]}
    echo "Temporary oldest date: "$oldestDateFound
    for date in "${arr[@]}"; do
     currentDate=$date
    if [[ "$currentDate" -lt "$oldestDateFound" ]]; then
      oldestDateFound=$currentDate
     else
      oldestDateFound=$currentOldestDate
     fi
    done
    echo "Oldest date found in directory: "$oldestDateFound
}
```

You can simplify this to

```
find_oldest_date () {
  oldest=$1
  shift
  for current; do
    [[ $current -lt $oldest ]] && current=$oldest
  done
  echo "Oldest date found in directory: $oldest"
}
```

Comment: Makes sense although i am trying to pass an array to the function

Comment: This works the same. You pass the *elements* of the array as separate arguments. Rather than gathering the arguments back into an array, I save the first one, then shift if off so that `$@` consists of the original `$2`, `$3`, etc. `for current; do` is just short for `for current in "$@"; do`.

Comment: I see. Makes sense. Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 1):

Note that you can just sort the arguments numerically:

```
find_oldest_date() {
   printf "%s\n" "$@" | sort -n | head -n1
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't the oldest be the `head`?

Answer (score 0):

Simplify.

```
$: filedates=(20200110 20200120 20200219 20200220 20200420 20200422 20200110 20200120 20200219 20200220 20200420 20200422 20200219 20200220 2020020 20200422)
$: find_oldest_date (){ printf "%s\n" "$@" | sort | head -1; }
$: find_oldest_date "${filedates[@]}"
20200110
```

Also...in your example, the first one *is* the oldest as far as I can see. Add a test value.

```
$: filedates=(20200110 20200120 20200219 20190220 20200420 20200422 20200110 20200120 20200219 20200220 20200420 20200422 20200219 20200220 2020020 20200422)
$: find_oldest_date "${filedates[@]}"
20190220
```

For efficiency -

```
find_oldest_date() {
  local oldest="$1"; 
  for d in "$@"; do [[ "$d" < "$oldest" ]] && oldest="$d"; done;
  echo "$oldest"; 
}
```

Comment: This spawns unnecessary external processes and does more work than is required. Sorting is O(n lg n); minimum is O(n).

Comment: Agreed, though if you expect a small list, the simplicity of maintenance is worth it. I only reinvent the wheel when the old one is a poor fit for the track.

I do totally agree with your statement, though.